# Google importhtml dynamic table need last 10 scores of cricketer

Tags: web-scraping, google-sheets, offset, google-sheets-formula, google-sheets-query

Creating a formula for looking dynamic last 10 cricket scores of a player.

i tried like below lines but due to dynamic player scores its always update solution :

`=(QUERY (IMPORTHTML("http://www.howstat.com/cricket/Statistics/Players/PlayerProgressSummary_T20.asp?PlayerID=3600","table"),"SELECT* LIMIT 10"))`

Any help with this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try:

```
=QUERY(IMPORTHTML("http://www.howstat.com/cricket/Statistics/Players/PlayerProgressSummary_T20.asp?PlayerID=3600", "table"),
 "offset "&COUNTA(INDEX(IMPORTHTML("http://www.howstat.com/cricket/Statistics/Players/PlayerProgressSummary_T20.asp?PlayerID=3600", "table"),,1))-10)
```

[image: 0]

Comment: Really ton thanks bro for this solution ,can i get only runs column and hide other columns and in transpose

Comment: sure if that was a question: `=TRANSPOSE(QUERY(QUERY(IMPORTHTML("http://www.howstat.com/cricket/Statistics/Players/PlayerProgressSummary_T20.asp?PlayerID=3600", "table"),
 "offset "&COUNTA(INDEX(IMPORTHTML("http://www.howstat.com/cricket/Statistics/Players/PlayerProgressSummary_T20.asp?PlayerID=3600", "table"),,1))-10), "select Col5", 1))`

Comment: this formula giving all data(i want only 10 last  dynamic scores)  excluding * scores where i want * this scores too, =(QUERY(QUERY(IMPORTHTML("http://www.howstat.com/cricket/Statistics/Players/PlayerProgressSummary_T20.asp?PlayerID=3600", "table"), "offset "&COUNTA(INDEX(IMPORTHTML("http://www.howstat.com/cricket/Statistics/Players/PlayerProgressSummary_T20.asp?PlayerID=3600", "table"),,1))-10), "select Col5",1)) this formula not displaying * scores

Comment: try: `=QUERY(QUERY(QUERY(IMPORTHTML("http://www.howstat.com/cricket/Statistics/Players/PlayerProgressSummary_T20.asp?PlayerID=3600", "table"),  "where not Col5 contains '*'", 1), "offset "&COUNTA(INDEX(IMPORTHTML("http://www.howstat.com/cricket/Statistics/Players/PlayerProgressSummary_T20.asp?PlayerID=3600", "table"),,1))-10), "select Col5", 1)`

Comment: ahh, I see... I understood it like you want to remove those numbers that had * ... try: `=ArrayFormula(QUERY(QUERY(TO_TEXT(IMPORTHTML("http://www.howstat.com/cricket/Statistics/Players/PlayerProgressSummary_T20.asp?PlayerID=3600", "table")), "offset "&COUNTA(INDEX(IMPORTHTML("http://www.howstat.com/cricket/Statistics/Players/PlayerProgressSummary_T20.asp?PlayerID=3600", "table"),,1))-10), "select Col5", 1))`

Comment: thanks it working kudoos,but it giving last 12 scores can i change formula to -8 to get 10 scores is this correct way

Comment: @RahulR sure, go for it

Comment: bro how to learn google sheets like you, as iam basically iam commerce background person

Comment: still beginner myself but all what is needed is testing and failing until you got it right. sadly there is no solid documentation

Comment: Thanks bro for all help and suggestions

Comment: Bro odi,t20 scores are fine ,but for test scores i am getting more than 10 last scores ,can you fix this bro =ArrayFormula(QUERY(QUERY(TO_TEXT(IMPORTHTML("http://howstat.com/cricket/Statistics/Players/PlayerProgressSummary.asp?PlayerID=3968", "table")), "offset "&COUNTA(INDEX(IMPORTHTML("http://howstat.com/cricket/Statistics/Players/PlayerProgressSummary.asp?PlayerID=3968", "table"),,1))-8), "select Col6", 1))

Comment: Bro Answer for the above comment is possible or not